# How to display thumbnail + tags + title of a child page?

Tags: post-thumbnails, tags, get-the-title

What do I need to do to display thumbnail + tags + title of a child page?

[ Thumbnail ]

[ Title ]

[ Tags ]

Thanks!

EDIT:
Well this work, but only showing thumbs+title... it shouldnt be too difficult to add the tags:

```
    <?php
    $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
    <?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
    <div class="child-thumb">
     <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></a><br />
     <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></a><br />
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: I've added the 1st post with the code

Comment: Did you enable post-type support for `post_tags`, for Pages?

Comment: Yupp! The tags works on pages, so no problem there! :)
I tried to add <?php echo get_the_tags($pageChild->ID); ?>, but that generates the word Array on the parent page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you've enabled support for both post thumbnails and post tags for static Pages, I would use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to build your query, and do something like the following:

```
global $post;
$child_pages_query_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order'
);

$child_pages = new WP_Query( $child_pages_query_args );

if ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="child-thumb">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php the_tags(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
endwhile; endif;

// Be kind; rewind
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note that I've not included any failsafes, such as checking for `has_post_thumbnail()`, etc.

Comment: Wonderful! Works great!

Comment: Glad to help! Be sure to *accept* the answer, by clicking the **checkmark** beneath the voting buttons, if it solved your issue. :)